# Setting value based on values in previous columns of the same table ? (Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm creating a new table and carrying over several columns from a previous table. One of the new fields that I need to create is a flag that will have values 0 or 1 and value needs to be determined based on 6 previous fields in the table.

The 6 previous columns have preexisting values of 'Y' (yes) or 'N' (no) stored for each one. This new field needs to check whether any of the 6 columns have Y and if so set the flag to 0. If there is N in all 6 fields then set itself to 1.

I was told to try and use greatest function but it doesnt seem to solve the problem that I have

```
select greatest('N','Y','N','Y') gr from dual;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `GREATEST()` does the trick.

For example:

```
select t.*, 
  case when greatest(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6) = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end as x 
from t
```

Result:

```
 F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  F6  X 
 --- --- --- --- --- --- - 
 N   N   N   N   N   N   1 
 N   N   N   Y   N   N   0 
 Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   0
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6041e8ec7aa3e9997652371c66345238).

Answer (score 0):

maybe try decode:  here are some hints.

```
decode( col1, 'N', 0, 1 )
```

this will give you a 0 if N otherwise a 1.  then add these up.

```
decode( col1, 'N', 0, 1 ) + decode( col2, 'N', 0, 1 ) + ...
```

then if > 0 you know at least one was Y

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing the columns with values, Yu can compare the value with columns. Like -

```
SELECT T.*, CASE WHEN 'N' IN (A, B, C, D, E, F) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEW_FIELD
FROM T;
```